# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException help me pls?

Tags: java

My code:

```
public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println( "What city is the capital of France?" );
        keyboard.next();

        System.out.println( "What is 6 multiplied by 7?" );
        keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "Enter a number between 0.0 and 1.0." );
        keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println( "Is there anything else you would like to say?" );
        keyboard.next();
    }

}
```

i run normal before a question Enter a number between 0.0 and 1.0. and it's error like this :

```
***What city is the capital of France?

Paris

What is 6 multiplied by 7?

442

Enter a number between 0.0 and 1.0.

0.5

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:28)
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)***
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Probably you entered wrong inputs by mistake, run again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scanner** will throw this exception if the entry is in a format that is incorrect for the Scanner's Locale. Particularly, in your case, if the wrong decimal separator is used. Both . and , are common locale-specific decimal separators.

To find out what the decimal separator is for your default locale you may use:

```
System.out.println(
    java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator()
);
```

See more in "original" topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028230/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-inputmismatchexception,).

Comment: Note: To make sure it is the decimal point, add the line `keyboard.useLocale(Locale.US);`